# I am trying to send textual data to Backend Node.js from Frontend React, but saves/accepts only upto 31k characters

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend, web-frontend

I have a problem in saving/sending text data to my Backend Node.js. When I send small amount of text data from Frontend React, it saves successfully in backend node.js. But problem arises only when I send large amount of text data more than 31k characters from Frontend React to Backend Node.js, it doesn't save/accept. It creates error in saving large data. I am using Jodit editor for text. Please help if someone knows the solution.

I am using Frontend as react and Backend as node.js
I have text editor jodit that I am using for frontend react. Through which I am trying to send large textual data to my backend node.js. But it is saving less than 31k characters in one time. I don't understand why it is not saving more than 31k characters in one go. I can save another 31k characters each time but not more than 31k characters. Please help me.

My Telegram ID-
@LethalDeath
@rv_2036